# Share the private respository

Tags: github

I have shared my private respository to another user(public account) via collaborator but my shared respository is not showing on their github desktop application. How could I share my respository to other user ?

Answer (score 1):

The user you invite should receive an email inviting them to the repository. Once the user has accepted the invitation, the user will have collaborator access to your repository.